# SPARK : Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark

I am running with Hadoop 2.7.0, hive 1.1.0 and spark 1.3.1. I have my metastore db in mysql database. I can create and view data from hive shell.

```html
hive (dwhdb)> select * from dwhdb.test_sample;
OK
test_sample.emp_id test_sample.emp_name test_sample.emp_dept test_sample.emp_sal
Eid1 EName1 EDept1 100.0
Eid2 EName2 EDept1 102.0
Eid3 EName3 EDept1 101.0
Eid4 EName4 EDept2 110.0
Eid5 EName5 EDept2 121.0
Eid6 EName6 EDept3 99.0
Time taken: 0.135 seconds, Fetched: 6 row(s)
```

But when I am trying to select same data from spark I am getting error

```html
hduser@ubuntu:~$ spark-shell
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.3.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_21)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
Spark context available as sc.
SQL context available as sqlContext.

scala> val sqlHContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
sqlHContext: org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext = org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext@5a8081b4

scala> sqlHContext.sql("SELECT emp_id, emp_name from dwhdb.test_sample").collect().foreach(println)
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:346)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.sessionState$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:239)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.sessionState(HiveContext.scala:235)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.hiveconf$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:251)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.hiveconf(HiveContext.scala:250)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.sql(HiveContext.scala:95)
 at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:24)
 at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:29)
 at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:31)
 at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:33)
 at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:35)
 at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:37)
 at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:39)
 at $iwC.<init>(<console>:41)
 at <init>(<console>:43)
 at .<init>(<console>:47)
 at .<clinit>(<console>)
 at .<init>(<console>:7)
 at .<clinit>(<console>)
 at $print(<console>)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
 at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
 at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1338)
 at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
 at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
 at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
 at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:856)
 at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:901)
 at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:813)
 at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:656)
 at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:664)
 at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:669)
 at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:996)
 at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:944)
 at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:944)
 at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
 at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:944)
 at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1058)
 at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
 at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
 at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
 at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
 at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
 at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
 at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1412)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:62)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:72)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2453)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2465)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:340)
 ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1410)
 ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "600s"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
 at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getInt(Configuration.java:1134)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.getIntVar(HiveConf.java:1211)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.getIntVar(HiveConf.java:1220)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:293)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:214)
 ... 61 more
```

Could you please let me know what can be the possible reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

The logs says you are trying to convert string '600s' to an Integer. Can you check where you are providing this.Looks like you have this in your hive-site.xml.
Please change it to '600'.